# Youtube Data API - Update description of playlistitems

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am trying to retrieve all my playlist videos and then update the description of each one of them. The code compiles and runs but the description is not getting updated in my videos. Any help will be appreciated. My code is:

```
        YouTube youtube = getYouTubeService();

        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("part", "snippet,contentDetails");
        parameters.put("maxResults", "50");
        parameters.put("playlistId", "PLTAcFSSQOSm42iD8uALkNSgu8lJAaiutG");

        //0-50
        YouTube.PlaylistItems.List playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest = youtube.playlistItems().list(parameters.get("part").toString());
        if (parameters.containsKey("maxResults")) {
            playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest.setMaxResults(Long.parseLong(parameters.get("maxResults").toString()));
        }

        if (parameters.containsKey("playlistId") && parameters.get("playlistId") != "") {
            playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest.setPlaylistId(parameters.get("playlistId").toString());
        }

        PlaylistItemListResponse response = playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest.execute();
        for (Iterator iterator = response.getItems().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            PlaylistItem type = (PlaylistItem) iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Title:");
            System.out.println(type.getSnippet().getTitle());
            System.out.println();
            String desc = type.getSnippet().getDescription();
            desc = desc.replace("\nAsk me A Question", "");
            desc = desc.replace("bit.ly\n", "");     

System.out.println("====================================================");
            PlaylistItemSnippet snippet = type.getSnippet();
            snippet.setDescription(desc);
            PlaylistItem playlistItem = type.setSnippet(snippet);
            System.out.println(playlistItem.getSnippet().getDescription());
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon researching for days on it. I have found that we can only update the Video objects and not PlayListItem objects. So I created a Video Object and set its properties and then in the Snippet section of the Video object, description can be updated.